# executing CTAKES NLP through eclipse

Tags: nlp, ctakes

I had tried to execute Ctakes NLP class `CTAKESClinicalPipelineFactory` class but got following error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.cleartk.classifier.liblinear.LIBLINEARStringOutcomeClassifierBuilder

Comment: have you found any solution, i am encountering somewhat similar problem?